# programming in c++ likes objectivec

Tags: c++

I used objectivec for 4 years and really like it.
Just wonder if can program in c++ likes objective-c.

```
1. c plus thin objective layer
2. use stl(Standard Template Library <iterator>、<vector>、<list> etc likes NSObjects in cocoa)
   + 
   standard c
   +
   basic c++ objective mode(Constructors and Destructors)

3. do not use complex c++ methods and pointer
```

If there is someone has done likes above or it is impossible/useless?

Your comment welcome

Comment: you can try, but i suspect that with nontrivial projects there will be cases where 'advanced' c++ creeps up on you. if you adopt smart-pointers and 'rule of zero' it will take you a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can defintely program C++ using just the C parts, RAII/constructors/destructors, and the STL.  In fact a lot of folks use C++ exactly this way.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done partly, use the macro. but it makes code too strange. Suggest you see the code cocos2d-x , it just copy the code of cocos2d , but it is the c++ version. It may be helpful.

link
[cocos2d-x git home](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x)